# Running a java program in batch

Tags: java, multithreading, batch-file, threadpool

I've created a java project in ItelliJ IDEA which consists of:

1. Main.java Class (contains the main() method)
2. FileOperations.java,
3. Zipper.java,
4. SFTPTransfer.java
5. CleanUp.java

Classes from 2 to 5 are instantiated in main() method (lies inside Main.java). This workflow works smoothly. Creates, Zips and ships a single file to SFTP server.

But I want to run the above program (i.e. call the main() method) at least over ten thousand times as I need to generate and ship that many files.

What is the best way to do so? Can it be simply achieved using some kind of batch files or would threads be a better alternative?

If I use threads then I'm not sure yet how to call main so many no of times.

Comment: Doesn't java have `for` loops that you can use?

Comment: You can paralelize using threads, you have io operations you are blocked to sftp server how many files can you upload concurrently

Comment: Hi Nachokk, I' have not measured the no of concurrent connections allowed to SFTP but thanks for asking because I definitely should look into that. May be I will try to take the transfer piece out of current workflow so I can transfer files in bulk in the end. Also, I'm currently facing some issue with my threads being terminated (comment below in Jason's answer), if you know of some way then please do share.

Comment: SomethingDark: Loops work but increase the execution time so I can't use that approach alone. I'm trying to combine looping with threads.

Answer (score 1):

One way to solve your problem is to:

1. Move the code from the main method to a separate method in the same class that represents performing the entire sequence of steps for a single file
2. In the main method, call your new method as many times as you need using whatever construct you prefer (for loop, while loop, thread executor, etc) for each file that needs to be processed.

Comment: Thanks Jason, after your answer I decided to use the threads as executing the code in a loop makes it take a lot of time, but for whatever reason, it works fine only if the no of threads are small (below 30 or so) otherwise for some reason the threads are terminated. From my understanding so far, this program shouldn't require synchronization of threads because each program is a step in the sequence whose execution can't be jumbled. What approach can I take to improve the performance?

Comment: Take measurements (timestamps) of the various blocks of code so that you understand which parts are taking the longest and therefore which parts will give you the best results from optimisation.